# PDO multiple fields insertion

Tags: mysql, pdo

I have a mysql database, with two tables; user and pairs INNODB.
the user table contains 8 fields.
Please how can i insert into just 3 fields out of the 8 fields using prepared statements? I;ve tried severaal means but it doesnt seem to work.

Comment: With any inserts, not just parameterized queries, you may only omit fields from an insert if they have defaults or are nullable.

Comment: Show the "several means" you've tried please.

Comment: Yes, I think 'nullable' was what I needed. I set my columns to nullable and it worked. thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Try this and fill in the correct value to the variables (based on my understanding of your question):

```
try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$server;dbname=$dbName", $serverUser, $serverPass);
    $conn -> setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $conn -> setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
} catch (PDOException $pdoErr) {
    echo "Database Error: ".$pdoErr->getMessage();
} catch (Exception $err) {
    echo "Error: ".$err->getMessage();
}

$editQuery = $conn -> prepare("INSERT INTO `users`(`column1`, `column2`, `column3`) VALUES (:value1, :value2, :value3)";
$editQuery -> execute(array('value1' => $value1, 'value2' => $value2, 'value3' => $value3));
```